# Rapid Application Developer 8.0.1: Unable to store working set state

Tags: ibm-rad

Since short time this message comes up in RAD in irregular intervals:

> Unable to store working set state.
>   C:\ws8\ws-mav-posflv.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workingsets.xml
>   (Der Vorgang ist bei einer Datei mit einem geöffneten Bereich, der
>   einem Benutzer zugeordnet ist, nicht anwendbar.)

There was a message on IBM site for this problem that this problem is fixed with RAD 7.5.5 and a workaround: [IBM Site](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK96112)

The workaround (give rights to everyone for the workingsets.xml) doesnt work.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem, on my system it was my anti-virus (Windows crap) who denied access to the file. Resolved by putting the `.metadata` folder in ignore.
Hope this helps, I know it's really annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disable your anti-virus program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. The solution that worked for me is : go the .exe file that starts the RAD. Right click and run as administartor. Running as admin did not give any issue. Environment : Windows 7 professional and RAD 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

moving the workspace directory into another folder (old folder had some sort of a permissions' issue) worked for me.